Why does R's NbClust use a lot of memory when run in bplapply?
this is my first post on stackoverflow, so please let me know if I need to improve something on my post.
In macOS (Apple M1 Max, 10 cores, 64 GB of RAM), I try to run NbClust in R on a small matrix. It works fine when run on a single core; it does not use a lot of memory (as expected) and CPU usage stays below 100% for the one core it is run on (so NbClust should not have internal multi-processing that might cause multi-multi-processing issues in conjunction with bplapply).
However, when I try to run it in parallel over multiple cores (using fork-ing, as on mac), memory quickly increases up to around 30-60 GB.
Here is a minimal example.
The first part with workers = 1 works fine.
The second part bloats memory excessively.
Any ideas why?
PS: I tried to use a for loop (manually assigning to a pre-instantiated list) instead of sapply but same result.
PS: I tried to leave out each index to see if it's related to one index but memory load is excessive in any case. I also tested another method ("ward.D") but also the same.
library(BiocParallel) # Install from Bioconductor
library(NbClust)

# Create a matrix of random positive numbers
mat <- matrix(runif(30 * 100, min = 0, max = 100),
              nrow = 30, ncol = 100)

indeces <- c("kl", "ch", "hartigan",
             "cindex", "db", "silhouette", "duda", "pseudot2",
             "ratkowsky", "ball", "ptbiserial", "gap",
             "mcclain", "gamma", "gplus", "tau", "dunn",
             "sdindex", "sdbw")

### Works fine ##############################################
param <- BiocParallel::MulticoreParam(workers = 1,
                                      progressbar = TRUE)

test <- BiocParallel::bplapply(
  X = 1:10,
  BPPARAM = param,
  function(i) {
    clust_results <- sapply(indeces, function(x) {
      tryCatch({
        NbClust::NbClust(data = mat, min.nc = 1, max.nc = 5,
                         method = "ward.D2", index = x)
      }, error = function(e) {
        return(NULL)
      })
    })
  }
)

### Excessive memory consumption ##############################
param <- BiocParallel::MulticoreParam(workers = 8,
                                      progressbar = TRUE)

test <- BiocParallel::bplapply(
  X = 1:10,
  BPPARAM = param,
  function(i) {
    clust_results <- sapply(indeces, function(x) {
      tryCatch({
        NbClust::NbClust(data = mat, min.nc = 1, max.nc = 5,
                         method = "ward.D2", index = x)
      }, error = function(e) {
        return(NULL)
      })
    })
  }
)


I found a hint for a solution mentioned here:
I used the hclust() function but from the package fastcluster. [...] it seems that it uses less memory than the default hclust().
So, as a solution, I copied the whole function code from the NbClust github repo R script file and replaced hclust with fastcluster::hclust.
Works now, with minimal memory usage plus it's even faster :)
